# Confused about Positioning in CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm totally lost, I just finished setting up my navigation bar **and now i can't seem to show the settings icon and the main text in any other position than fixed...** here is my code sample , it can't show images

This is the entire relevant code, the html, as well as the css.

The end result should be a navigationbar, similar to the one that facebook uses for "Groups".

HTML(php):

```
    <div style='width:100%;max-height:31px;position:relative;top:1px;overflow:hidden;'>

        <div style='width:2000px;max-height:31px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;'>

            <div class='groups_navi-active' id='navbar-groupname'>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left; width:11px;'>
                </div>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left;'>
                ".$navbar_groupname."
                </div>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left;width:11px;'>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class='groups_navi-inactive' id='navbar-structure'>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left; width:11px;'>
                </div>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left;'>
                Structure
                </div>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left;width:11px;'>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='groups_navi-inactive' id='navbar-explore'>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left; width:11px;'>
                </div>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left;'>
                Explore!
                </div>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left;width:11px;'>
            </div>

        </div>



        <div class='groups_navi-right'>

        </div>


    </div>





    <div style='float:right;position:fixed;top:42px;height:22px;width:796px;z-index:1'>

        <div class='groups_navi-settingsicon' id='groups_navi-settingsicon' ></div>

        <div style='clear:both;'></div>

<!-- THIS IS HIDDEN AND WILL BE MADE VISIBLE WITH JAVASCRIPT !-->    
        <div id='navbar-settings-list' style='border-left:1px solid #787878;border-right:1px solid #787878;border-top:1px solid #787878;background-color:#ffffff;border-bottom:2px solid #283d6c;background color:#ffffff;float:right;display:none;z-index:5;'>
            <div style='width:126px;height:4px;'></div>
            <div class='groups-navi-settings-list_option-inactive' id='groups-navi-settings-list_option--deletegroup' title='".$_GET['groupid']."'>
            Delete Group
            </div>
            <div style='width:126px;height:4px;'></div>
        </div>

    </div>







    <div style='z-index:8;position:fixed;width:796px'>

        <div>
        <img src='IMG/texticon.png'>
        </div>
        <div>
        ".$groupoverview_groupdescription."
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.groups_navi-active
{
height:30px;position:relative;line-height:30px;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#000000;
float:left;
z-index:2;
}

.groups_navi-inactive
{
float:left;
height:30px;
position:relative;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
border-left:1px solid #dbdbdb;
border-right:0px;
border-top:0px;
line-height:30px;
font-size:11px; 
font-weight:bold;
color:#818181;
z-index:2;
}


.groups_navi-right
{
float:left;
height:30px;
width:1000px;
position:relative;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
border-left:1px solid #dbdbdb;
border-right:0px;
border-top:0px;
line-height:30px;
font-size:11px; 
font-weight:bold;
color:#818181;
}


.groups_navi-settingsicon
{
width:31px;height:22px;background: url('../IMG/navbar-stgs.png');float:right;background-position: 0 0;
}


.groups_navi-settingsicon-active
{
width:31px;height:22px;background: url('../IMG/navbar-stgs.png');float:right;background-position: 0 -22;
}

.groups-navi-settings-list_option-inactive
{
width:126px; height: 18px;text-align:center;line-height:18px;
border-top:1px solid #ffffff;
border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
}

.groups-navi-settings-list_option-inactive:hover
{
width:126px; height: 18px;text-align:center;line-height:18px;background-color:#6c83b6;color:#f8ffff;
border-top:1px solid #39579b;
border-bottom:1px solid #39579b;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: A friend just spotted the mistake, i forgot to close a div here:

<div class='groups_navi-inactive' id='navbar-explore'>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left; width:11px;'>
                </div>

                <div style='height:30px;float:left;'>
                Explore!
                </div>

                ***<div style='height:30px;float:left;width:11px;'>***
            </div>
</div>

Comment: Don't use inline CSS and CSS in a style sheet - the inline always wins, so things become complex quickly. I'd only ever use inline CSS in extreme situations, such as a self contained file that had to exist alone or something weird…

Answer (score 0):

The container (parent div) of your settings icon is position:fixed.  That will override your float:right.  In fact, I see two instances of using position:fixed without setting the X/Y offsets, which really just doesn't work.

If that's not it... I think you'll have better answers if you can boil your code down to the problematic areas.

Comment: i originally used fixed to position the icon on top of the grey area on the right, but now that i need my page to scroll this became problematic and i need another solution, which at the moment i just can't find.

Answer (score 0):

I think you sould check the images path , its must be correct 
I had made sample of it on this url 
http://jsfiddle.net/563Vx/

feel free to update this fiddle

Comment: the path is just fine, my problem is getting the icon in a proper position with a position different from fixed.